# I am not sure if I am interpreting this regular expression correctly

Tags: regex

This RegEx exists inside an xsd file

```
[^~|\t\n\r]+(~[^~|\t\n\r]+)?(\|[^~|\t\n\r]+(~[^~|\t\n\r]+)?)*
```

I am still pretty new to deciphering regular expressions.
I understand that that \t\n\r refer to tab, new line and carriage return
I have found that ^ inside of [ ] means "not"
But I am missing the intricacies of this particular regex.

Can it be broken out like so?

```
"[^~|\t\n\r]
+
(~[^~|\t\n\r]+)
?
(\|[^~|\t\n\r]
+
(~[^~|\t\n\r]+)?)*"
```

Does the first piece mean "not | or tab or new line or carriage return?

The other sections seem nearly the same with the addition or change of ~ and \ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes, essentially: `firstmatch~secondoptionalmatch` possibly repeated with `|`'s in between (the `\|` is a literal `|`). So `aa~bb|cc|dd~ff|gg` would match for instance.

Comment: I've found http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about `\t`, `\n` and `\r` being tabs and line feeds.

So you have a repeated character class `[^~|\t\n\r]+`. This represents "one or more characters which can be anything other than `~`, `|`, `\t`, `\n` or `\r`.

The pattern starts with one of these.

It then has another one, prefixed with a `~` character, which is optional (the `?` makes it optional and the brackets make the optional bit include both the `~` and the character class).

You then have another set of brackets with a `*` after it, which means "repeat zero or more times. This set of brackets contains a third instance of your character class, this time preceded by a `|`, and then another optional one preceded by a `~`.

This block with brackets and a `*` at the end is basically a repetition of the whole of the rest of the pattern. What it boils down to is a repeating pattern of strings separated by `|` character, each of which is optionally sub-divided into two by a `~` separator character.

Answer (score 1):

There are [tools that can sort this out for you](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zwCAefSqeilMHk3j):

[image: Breakdown of regex]

As for the utility of this expression, that entirely depends on what input it's being fed within your application.